# What is the term "Usage"?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I am seeing this a lot in the scripts. Is "usage" a command in unix ?

I tried googling it but got ambiguous results. Here is an example  `: ${1?"Usage: $0 ARGUMENT"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 'Usage' is not a command. In the case of your example it is the output to be printed to the screen if there isn't an argument run behind the command.

It's basically saying if you see $1 variable then continue, else print this information to the terminal to help explain.

For example, lets say I run the commnad `./foobar`. It will exit and print 'Usage: foobar ARGUMENT'. If I instead run `./foobar option1`, then the program is launched with the variable $1 containing 'option1'.

Comment: Okay. so if i write this as an example can you please check if i am getting this right.

`: ${var1?"The var1 is not existent"}` This would check if the var1 is set or not and would print the message in case the variable is not set. Am i getting it right Jeight?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Awesome! Voting up and Thank you. The "usage" doubt goes to /dev/null :D